# Definable subset of the additive theory of integers

Tags: model-theory

I strongly suspect that the subset $\{ -1,1 \}$ of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is not definable, despite being fixed under all automorphisms of the structure. However, I can't seem to be able find a proof. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I agree with your suspicions. At the same time, finding a proof is a lot more difficult than I expected.

Comment: you might check out this overflow answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78727/definable-subsets-of-the-integers-as-an-abelian-subgroup

Comment: @greg: thanks for your comment! I was just about to type up essentially the same answer as the one in the MO question you cite.